# Set-Cookie in response header is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular, http, cookies

I have my backend(Ruby On Rails) running at port number 3000 with login endpoint(http://localhost:3000/login).I also have angular server running on port 4200.So with angular I am hitting login endpoint and upon successful login, response is sent back with **Set-cookie** option(authentication token is set).But it is not set in the browser.Below is the response header i am receiving:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:POST, GET, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://localhost:4200
Access-Control-Max-Age:1728000
Cache-Control:max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8
ETag:W/"9dae161444bc908fd3289f4ed0fb15ed"
Set-Cookie:auth_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJ1c2VyX2lkIjoyLCJleHAiOjE1MDU4NDM0Nzh9.0E22wlacZWvmazpdJPLC4oRq3QM-8DX-npQu3w-U8Vs; path=/
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
Vary:Origin
X-Request-Id:267cfe1f-e60c-40b5-9a7b-4801d358cfd4
X-Runtime:0.273751
Request Headers
view source
```

While if I hit that API with Postman then the cookie is saved without problem.

Comment: Are you using proxy.conf?

Comment: @Z.Bagley I am not familiar with proxy.conf.Can you please explain it's role ?

Comment: It's used in Angular-CLI projects in order to handle proxy requests

Comment: If it is by default then I would be using it otherwise haven't set it up.

Comment: There's a file call **proxy.conf.json** where you can set up your http requests to proxy to the right port. You then use `ng serve -pc proxy.conf.json` to serve your app to make sure it forwards to request to the back-end

Comment: where is this file located?

Comment: In the root of your angular-cli project

Comment: Thank you , I got problem it was in server side cors middleware.

Comment: @AvaneeshKumar Can you please specify what caused the problem? I'm facing similar issue with a Wordpress Backend running on http://localhost/~XXXX/wordpress

Comment: @AvaneeshKumar - could you explain what was the issue. I am facing similar issue (Play backend). I am not sure if the issue could be due to the server

Comment: For me the issue was that the `Set-Cookie` had the `secure` flag (true) and I wasn't using `HTTPS`. I removed `secure` to make it work on my `locahost` environment without `HTTPS`